# How do I correctly update User state in React with a has_many :trails, through: :reviews association, after deleting a review?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, state, relational-database, has-many

[ERD for my API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UttB.png)

`Users` have many `reviews`, and many `trails` through `reviews`, and vice versa.

Goal:

1. On a `user` profile page, render a list of names of `trails` that `user` has reviewed, without duplicating any of the `trail` names. For example, if a `user` has reviewed a `trail` more than once, it should only display the `trail` name once. If a `user` has reviewed a `trail` multiple times, and deletes one of those `reviews`, the list should still display the `trail` name. If all of the `user's` `reviews` for that `trail` have been deleted, the `trail` name should be removed from the rendered list.
2. When a `review` is deleted, update frontend `user` state so that `user.reviews` and `user.trails` are accurate, without making a `GET` request to do so.

What I've tried:

Create a `set` of unique `trail` names from `user.trails` and then render them in JSX by mapping over them

```js
const uniqTrailNames = [...new Set(user.trails.map((trail) => {
  return trail.name
}))]
```

```js
{(uniqTrailNames.map((name) => {
  return <p key={name}>{name}</p>
}))}
```

This is successful in rendering a unique list of `trail` names from the `trails` a `user` has reviewed. However, I'm struggling to `setUser` state correctly when a `review` is deleted.

Currently, my `handleDelete()` function successfully destroys the `review` in the database, and then calls `setUser` in order to update `user.reviews` and `user.trails`, but this is where I'm updating the `trails` property incorrectly. Filtering this way removes all `user.trails` objects with id's that match the `review's` associated `trail_id`, so even if the `user` had another `review` of the `trail`, the `trail` name doesn't render because the `trails` no longer exist in `user.trails`. How do I go about removing only a single `trail` object when deleting a `review`, so that `user.trails` remains accurate, if `trail` objects are essentially identical? Am I going about this the wrong way? It's part of my project requirement to showcase the full `has_many` `through` relationship, so that's why I've taken this approach so far.

```js
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from '../contexts/UserContext'
import { TrailsContext } from '../contexts/TrailsContext'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

function UserTrailReview({ review }) {

    const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext)
    const {trails, setTrails} = useContext(TrailsContext)
    const {
        id,
        trail_id,
        trail_rating,
        condition,
        content,
        formatted_date,
        trailname
    } = review

    const trail = trails.find((trail) => {
       return trail.id === trail_id
    })

    function handleDelete() {
        fetch(`/reviews/${id}`, {
            method: "DELETE"
        })
       .then(setUser({
            ...user,
            reviews: user.reviews.filter((review) => {
                return review.id !== id
            }),
            trails: user.trails.filter((trail) => {
                return trail.id !== trail_id
            })
        }))
        .then(() => {
            trail.reviews = trail.reviews.filter((review) => {
                return review.id !== id
            })
            const updatedTrails = trails.map((t) => {
                if (t.id === trail_id) {
                    return trail
                } else {
                    return t
                }
            })
            setTrails(updatedTrails)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to avoid the duplication issue in the first place is to use the Active Record Query Method "distinct". In your models, wherever you have a has_many, through relationship, use distinct like so:

`has_many :trails, -> { distinct }, through: :reviews`